# How to ensure that it is actually opened the serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I need to open a port to the serial device but if it has not been opened or there is an exception it must continuously  try to open the door until it opens. Python 2.7.3 after a while I get this error:

> "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python
>   object"

Can you help me?

My code:

```
def opendisplay():
    try:
        lcd = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/display', 
        baudrate=9600, 
        timeout=0,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
        )
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error! can't connect to display Lcd check USB-Serial \n" + str(e)
        opendisplay()   
    return lcd

dsp=opendisplay()
```

Comment: Stop recursing and start looping.

Comment: You call the code again when it fails. Just don't do that, or at least wait for some time (e.g. a minute) before trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin/Shadow says, loop instead of recurse:

```
def opendisplay():
    while True:
        try:
            # Try to connect
            lcd = serial.Serial(...)
            return lcd
        except Exception as e:
            # Connection failed
            print "Error! etc"
            time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to only keep trying for a minute, you can use `for _ in range(60)` instead